# How to render lists of column values into a table using a template (such as Jinja2)

Tags: python, html, templates, jinja2

I am trying to do the following (doesn't work, just shown to convey the intended behavior):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>

  {% for col1_val in col1_values %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ col1_val }}</td>
      <td>{{ col2_values[col1_values.index(col1_val)] }}</td>
      <td>{{ col3_values[col1_values.index(col1_val)] }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

where the table desired is:

```
Column 1       Column 2       Column 3
col1_values[0] col2_values[0] col3_values[0]
col1_values[1] col2_values[1] col3_values[1]
.
.
.
```

where col1_values are unique from each other.

How should the Jinja2 template be rewritten to achieve the desired table output? Is it possible without having to transpose the dimensions of col1_values, col2_values and col3_values? If not, what would be the most Pythonic way of doing the transpose?

Comment: Is it not <td>{{ col1_val }}</td>? not <th>.

Comment: Why not use a nested list instead? `table_values = [[col1_value_0, col2_value_0, col3_value_0], [col1_value_1, col2_value_1, col3_value_1], ...]`? The `zip()` function can combine the 3 `colX_values` lists if need be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I passed `zip(col1_values,col2_values,col3_values)` to the template as `row_values` and accessed the table elements as `row.0`, `row.1` and `row.2` from the `{% for row in row_values %}` loop, and it worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a nested list instead? Loop over a structure like:

```
table_values = [[col1_value_0, col2_value_0, col3_value_0], [col1_value_1, col2_value_1, col3_value_1], ...]
```

The [zip() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) can combine the 3 colX_values lists if need be:

```
table_rows = zip(col1_values, col2_values, col3_values)
```

Now you have per-row lists to loop over:

```
{% for col1_val, col2_val, col3_val in table_rows %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ col1_val }}</td>
    <td>{{ col2_val }}</td>
    <td>{{ col3_val }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have three lists col1_values, col2_values and col3_values. In views, construct list of lists as:

```
col_values = zip(col1_values, col2_values, col3_values)
```

Pass col_values to template and do the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>

  {% for col1, col2, col3 in col_values %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ col1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ col2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ col3 }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I think this would be easy method to solve your problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this but got an unpacking error in the for loop: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: Are you sure that you have this in your code: col_values = [col1_values, col2_values, col3_values]. Where col1_values, col2_values, col3_values should be list.

Comment: yes, i think your code just lacked the zip() step... `col_values = zip(col1_values, col2_values, col3_values)` works.